# is there a way to link color point to a dictionary with the different legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, legend

I want to bind label to color after doing the scatter plot and the colorization, is there a way to get the colors as arg, set a legend to each color and, if the color is in the plot, add the legend/label to the plot

I have a large dataset of point in 6D
I printed them in 2 dimensions (D1vsD2,D1vsD3...)
I gave them color depending on specific data

I have a dictionary with the different labels which correspond to the colors meaning

```py
matrix = [[1,1,1,1,1,2]
          [2,2,2,2,2,3]
          [3,3,3,3,3,4]]
legend = {0: "this is blue",1:"this is orange",2:"this is green"...}
#obviously my dataset is bigger (matrix with 25 000 lines) so it is an example

data = np.asarray(matrix)

for x in range(6):
            for y in range(6):
                if x != y:
                    colors = []
                    for line in raw_data:
                        if x==1 and y==2:
                            colors.append('C0') #blue
                        elif x==0 and y==2:
                            colors.append('C1') #orange

                        elif x==1 and y==3:
                            colors.append('C2') #green

        
                    plt.figure()

                    plt.scatter(data.T[x],data.T[y], s=50, linewidth=0, c=colors, alpha=0.7)
```

The result is a beautiful graph with 2 axes that correspond to column 1 and column 2 with point and color for each point (or not if not referenced)

I want to add a legend to the graph if they are point of the color said in the graph

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if i could, i would provide only a picture and ask for link legend to color, how i set the color in my code depend on some external data which would be to complicated to provide

Comment: Google for "matplotlib legend proxy artist".

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='The red data')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch])
```

you can create a longer handles is you create a list of mpatches.Patches
from https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html